# Running specs2 test on IntelliJ throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, specs2

I have Scala Play project which uses `specs2` as the test framework. I'm having difficult time running the tests from IntelliJ. I get the following error:

```
InvocationTargetException for 'main' in org.specs2.NotifierRunner: null


Process finished with exit code 0
```

The tests run successfully from `sbt`. I have seen few other posts which says it could be due to `ScalaTestPlus`, but I don't use `ScalaTest`.

Here is what my dependencies look like

**`build.sbt`**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ws,
  guice,
  specs2 % Test,
...
)
```

**`project/plugins.sbt`**

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.6")

...
```

The test looks like following:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyAppSpec extends PlaySpecification with Mockito {
...
```

Comment: What is the command you are using that works in `sbt`?

Comment: Can you please run `sbt> show externalDependencyClasspath` and check what's the specs2 version? You might want to try `specs2-core-4.10.5`

Comment: What run configuration do you use to run tests? Check the https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-and-test-scala.html#test_scala_app

Comment: @TomerShetah I'm just running `sbt test`
@Eric I don't see `specs2` on the `show externalDependencyClasspath`. I attempted adding `dependencyOverrides += "org.specs2" % "specs2" % "3.7" % Test` and `dependencyOverrides += "org.specs2" % "specs2-core" % "4.10.6" % Test` without any success
@Andrey yes I did follow the configuration explained on the Jetbrains documentation

Answer (score 1):

just leave a comment for someone still struggling, hope it help.

I faced the same error, it cause by i just use a different scala version with specs2. i specific scala binary version as `2.12` but import a specs2 compiled with `2.11`.